# Is a parent-reference in a child justifiable if the child cannot exist without a parent?

Tags: c#, oop

For example, each human can have multiple children but each human must have two parents. Is it justifiable to then say (in C#)

```
class Human {}

class Father : Human
{
    List<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

class Mother : Human
{
    List<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

class Child : Human
{
    Mother Mother {get; set;} 
    Father Father {get; set;}
}
```

(Another example would be pages of a book - a book can have multiple pages but a page must belong to one and only one book, assuming we do not introduce notions of tearing pages out of books, adding pages, etc)

I know that in OOP a parent reference in a child object breaks encapsulation and increases coupling. However if it does not make sense for a child object to not have a parent, then is it right to add a parent-reference to the child object?

Comment: A human does not have to be a mother. Thus you can create a class `Human`, a `Mother` derived from it, a `Child` derived from `Human` as well. `Child` _is a_ `Human`, but it _has a_ `Mother`, thus it should have a `Mother` property. `Mother` can have multiple `Child`, thus it should have a property `List<Child>`.

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed more appropriate. Updated the question.

Comment: Actually I would say that a Parent (`Father`/`Mother`) should hold a list of `Human` instead of `Child` in the case of semantics. Supposing `Human` parents have `Human` children, those children themselves can turn into a `Father` or a `Mother`. Same goes for a childs parents (should be `Human` since parents are somebodies children) This removes a circular dependency, although there is nothing technically wrong about what you are doing and in certain cases is a perfectly legitimate way of describing objects.

Comment: I don't necessarily see the value in having classes for Mother, Father or Child.  A Mother has her own Mother, so which class type should she be instantiated as; Mother or Child?  You could simply have the Human class with properties for Mother/Father holding those references, and a List of Children.  There could be properties called `IsFather` and `IsMother` which returns true/false based on the count of children in the children list...

Comment: @Idle_Mind it could be useful if the application's task was to deal with a set of minors, for whom `Father` and `Mother` would exist as people with a particular relationship to them (though that they may not have guardianship or that they could be other guardians would also have to be considered). While not sensible generally, it could be in a particular app.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that in OOP a parent reference in a child object breaks encapsulation…

No it doesn't. If code from the outside should have a reason to care that there is such a relationship, then code from the outside show be allowed to know. Code doesn't need to know whether or not that relationship is implemented by a reference, and indeed it doesn't have to be. Revealing that is what would break encapsulation.

> …and increases coupling.

Ah, well that it does.

So you need to either:

1. Be happy that you don't care about this.
2. Deal with the coupling in a well-defined place.

An easy way to be happy that you don't care, is if your classes are immutable: When you receive a `Human` its `Mother`, `Father` and/or `Children` properties are fixed and read-only then the coupling is also fixed and not going to hurt you. (It might if you had a reference-counted garbage collection, but this is .NET so you don't). That's not the only way you might not care, but it is one.

Otherwise you need to deal with that coupling. One way is to have only the `Mother` and `Father` properties settable from the outside. Consider:

```
public class Human
{
  private Human _mother;
  private Human _father;
  private HashSet<Human> _children;
  public IEnumerable<Human> Children
  {
    // If paranoid, do a foreach … yield here to stop code casting back to `HashSet`
    // Using ImmutableCollections and calling ToImmutableHashSet() is good too.
    get { return _children; } 
  }
  public Human Mother
  {
    get { return _mother; }
    set
    {
      if(_mother == value) // skip for no-op
        return;
      if(_mother != null)
        _mother._children.Remove(this);
      if(value != null)
        value._children.Add(this);
      _mother = value;
    }
  }
  public Human Father
  {
    get { return _father; }
    set
    {
      if(_father == value)
        return;
      if(_father != null)
        _father._children.Remove(this);
      if(value != null)
        value._children.Add(this);
      _father = value;
    }
  }
}
```

This approach deals with the coupling by having it handled in the `Father` and `Mother` properties, and only in those properties. Other approaches suit other cases, such as for example not storing the values for these properties at all but having a means to obtain them when the properties are invoked.

It's certainly also possible to have all of the `Mother`, `Father` and `Children` properties writable (and the collection obtained by accessing `Children` writable as well)` and still keep in sync, it's just hard. Whether it's harder than it has to be depends on the application.

Rather than break encapsulation, they very much depend upon it.